# jQuery wait for an action to complete on different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have created a newsfeed. The feed switches every 2 seconds. You can also manually switch left/right, or click the panel from the squares at the bottom. The switching between slides is down using jQuery UI Slide.

Right now, if you are in the middle of a slide, and you click left/right/squares, then another slide occurs on top of the existing, still going slide and the whole system is messed up.

How can I prevent other actions occurring if a slide/switch is already in progress?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    newsfeedTimer = setInterval(newsfeed, displayDuration);

    // Manual change of feed (LEFT)
    $('#newsfeeds_wrapper > .left').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        feedLeft();
        clearInterval(newsfeedTimer);   
        newsfeedTimer = setInterval(newsfeed, displayDuration);
    });
    // Very similar code for feed right
    // Ignore the other method of switching (if it works for above, I can implement it for this one)

});

function newsfeed() {
   feedRight();
}
// Feed to the Right
// jump is used to jump multiple newsfeed instead of one at a time
function feedRight(jump)
{
    jump = typeof jump !== 'undefined' ? jump : 1;
    var current = $('.newsfeed:first');
    var next    = $('.newsfeed:nth(' + jump + ')');
    current.hide('slide',{duration: transitionDuration}, function(){
    // Append as many needed
    for( var i = 0; i < jump; i++ ) {
        $('.newsfeed:first').appendTo('#newsfeeds');
    }
    next.show('slide',{direction : 'right' , duration: transitionDuration});    
}
```

I don't want to `stop()` an animation! I want to disable changing the slides IF there is animation happening!!

Comment: Without any type of code, you could look at the jQuery UI API and see how to stop whatever you're talking about. Or if it's animations, look into jQuery's `stop()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without seeing the full breadth of the code, I am shooting myself in the foot here. But here is a direction I would take it. You could also have two functions, one to bind, another to unbind. When animation is initiated, you unbind the left/right controls. When stopped, you bind. Or, set a global variable... ala.

```
var config = {'inProgress': false};
$('#newsfeeds_wrapper > .left').click(function(event){
    if(!config.inProgress){
      event.stopPropagation();
      feedLeft();
      clearInterval(newsfeedTimer);   
      newsfeedTimer = setInterval(newsfeed, displayDuration);
   }
});
```

in your animation function. Seems like when you cut/paste, some of the code is lost, so lets just assume some animation.

when you enter your animation functions, set config.inProgress = true;

```
function feedRight(jump)
{
  config.inProgress = true;
  // removed your code, but just using for simplicity sake
  // added a callback 
    next.show('slide',{direction : 'right' , duration: transitionDuration},
      function() {
       // Animation complete. Set inProgress to false
       config.inProgress = false;
      });
    )
}
```